# List of Lists GroupBy

Tags: kotlin

How can I succesfully do something like this?

```
trips.groupBy { Passenger::name if Passenger in it.passengers}
```

I want to reorder the `List<Trips>` which has a `List<Passengers>` to be `[PassengerA: List<Trips>, PassengerB:...]`

Comment: Need a little more info. If Trips has a list of Passengers, do you want to create new lists of Trips instances where the lists of passengers only have one passenger so it makes sense to link them to a single passenger? Or do you want each Passenger to be linked to a list of Trips they are a member of, such that the same Trips instance will appear multiple times in the final map since it is linked to multiple different passengers?

Comment: the answer below is 95% of what I needed, i just forgot to add some info I added as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, this could be a way to do what you want:

```kotlin
val passengersToTrips = trips
    .flatMap { trip ->
        // Associate every passenger in a trip to the trip: this results in a List<Pair<Passenger, Trip>>
        trip.passengers.map { passenger -> passenger to trip }
    }
    .groupBy(
        // Group using the passenger as key (use passenger.name in case the name should be the key)
        keySelector = { (passenger, _) -> passenger },
        // Extracting only the trip from the pair to transform from List<Pair<Passenger, Trip> into List<Trip> 
        valueTransform = { (_, trip) -> trip }
    )
```

Comment: thank you so much! this is exactly what i need but i ommitted one piece of information. How can I also take into account passengers that are in a list of allPassengers, so that they are also included as Passenger:A : emptyList() ? what is a good moment to use `Passenger::name`? I am still learning, sorry for the questions

Comment: You could just add to the Map the passengers which are not in it: `val withEmpty = passengersToTrips + (allPassengers - passengersToTrips.keys).associateWith { emptyList() }`

Comment: We can also do this with: `allPassengers.associateWith { passengersToTrips[it] ?: emptyList() }`.

Comment: thanks everyone so much. i am just starting with kotlin (1 week in) and this style is very difficult for me. Any book recommendations would be highly appreciated, and also, what do you think of Atomic Kotlin?

Comment: @broot could you explain a bit how does this work under the hood, i dont really understand how does the allpassangers list can be rearranged based on passangers to trips[it]... so that I can apply this concept in many scenarios

Comment: @gpunto, why in the main answer, does using only map instead of flatmap return a List<List<Pair<A,B>>?

Comment: `map` transforms a `List<A>` into a `List<B>` where `B` is what you return inside the lambda. If you return a `List<Pair>`, then `map` will return a `List<List<Pair>>`. `flatMap` not only maps but also flattens the result.

Comment: thanks @gpunto, let me know if you can help me with my other question i recently posted :)